# Why does Eclipse starts something at localhost?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse. I've written a simple java application :

```
// Hello.java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Hello, Java!");
    }
}
```

When I run it, the Debug tab (in Eclipse) shows me the following:

```
Hello (Java Application)
   |
    - Hello at localhost:51735
         |
          - Thread [main] (Running)
```

Why does it show me the "localhost:51735"?

Comment: because you are running the Hello class locally

Comment: In order to debug the application, you need a communications channel between the debugger and the program. This is done using a socket bound to localhost on a random port. This is what it means by 'localhost:51735' - it's the communications channel between eclipse's debugger and the program

Comment: Ofcourse. My class has nothing to do with web. I'm not creaing any kind of a web service... I just want to write a console application in Java

Comment: @Petesh You mean that this is just how the java debugger works?

Comment: Yes, that is how the debugger works.

Comment: Thank you to all